# Use typescript in a new Laravel+Inertia+React app

Tags: typescript, laravel, inertiajs

I am installing Laravel from scratch... followed the guide...

When adding breeze I should be able to select typescript but it seems this option is not available anymore because it does not ask me neither allow me to use it as a flag --typescript...

I install anyway but now Inertia expect every file to be named *.jsx but I really want to use *.tsx

Does anyone know any way to use typescript anyway?

Comment: Typescript support was added in Breeze v1.20.0, released on 2023-03-20. Make sure you are using at least this version (or newer).

Comment: This is correct! I had installed php 8.0 so it was not going to latest laravel